# Using BeautifulSoup to extract text within a tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a text within a site source code using BeautifulSoup. **Part of** the source code looks like this:

```
        <hr />
        <div class="see-more inline canwrap" itemprop="genre">
            <h4 class="inline">Genres:</h4>
<a href="/genre/Horror?ref_=tt_stry_gnr"
> Horror</a>&nbsp;<span>|</span>
<a href="/genre/Mystery?ref_=tt_stry_gnr"
> Mystery</a>&nbsp;<span>|</span>
<a href="/genre/Thriller?ref_=tt_stry_gnr"
> Thriller</a>
        </div>
```

So I have been trying to extract the texts 'horror' 'mystery' and 'thriller' with these codes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url1='http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5308322/?ref_=inth_ov_tt'
r1=requests.get(url1)
soup1= BeautifulSoup(r1.text, 'lxml')
genre1=soup1.find('div',attrs={'itemprop':'genre'}).contents
print(genre1)
```

But the return comes out as:

```
['\n', <h4 class="inline">Genres:</h4>, '\n', <a href="/genre/Horror?
ref_=tt_stry_gnr"> Horror</a>, '\xa0', <span>|</span>, '\n', <a 
href="/genre/Mystery?ref_=tt_stry_gnr"> Mystery</a>, '\xa0', <span>|</span>, 
'\n', <a href="/genre/Thriller?ref_=tt_stry_gnr"> Thriller</a>, '\n']
```

I am pretty new at python and webscraping, so I would appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use straight-forward `BeautifulSoup.select()` function to extract the needed elements to *CSS* selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5308322/?ref_=inth_ov_tt'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url1).text, 'lxml')
genres = [a.text.strip() for a in soup.select("div[itemprop='genre'] > a")]

print(genres)
```

The output:

```
['Horror', 'Mystery', 'Thriller']
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simply beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I am using html.parser. Let us know if you face any problems:

```
 for data in genre1:
     get_a = data.find_all("a")
     text = ""
     for i in get_a:
         text = i.text
         print(text)
```

Please check the indentation as I am using cellphone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BeautifulSoup `get_text()` method indstead od the `.contents` property to get what you want:

---

**From [get_text() documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):**

*If you only want the text part of a document or tag, you can use the get_text() method. It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string:*

```
markup = '<a href="http://example.com/">\nI linked to <i>example.com</i>\n</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)

soup.get_text()
>>> u'\nI linked to example.com\n'
soup.i.get_text()
>>> u'example.com'
```

*You can specify a string to be used to join the bits of text together:*

```
soup.get_text("|")
>>> u'\nI linked to |example.com|\n'
```

*You can tell Beautiful Soup to strip whitespace from the beginning and end of each bit of text:*

```
soup.get_text("|", strip=True)
>>> u'I linked to|example.com'
```

*But at that point you might want to use the .stripped_strings generator instead, and process the text yourself:*

```
[text for text in soup.stripped_strings]
>>> [u'I linked to', u'example.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same in several ways. Css selectors are precise, easy to understand and less error prone. So you can go with selectors as well to serve the purpose:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup            
import requests

link = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5308322/?ref_=inth_ov_tt'

res = requests.get(link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'lxml')
genre = ' '.join([item.text.strip() for item in soup.select(".canwrap a[href*='genre']")])
print(genre)
```

Result:

```
Horror Mystery Thriller
```